# Is it possible to automate hdmi output sound to tv and vice versa in a macbook pro?

Tags: mac, audio, hdmi

I'm with a macbook pro (2009) that has a mini display port. I've already bought a hdmi cable, and external output to a lcd tv is possible.

My question is: I have to manually change the sound output, from speaker to tv, and from tv to speaker when I take off the cable.

Is it possible to automatically transfer - or at least have a small switch next to the clock - the sound from speaker to tv when I connect the cable, and from tv to speaker when I disconnect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, I've found a solution myself! It's called "[SoundSource](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/freebies/)". Great!

Comment: Realtek onboard sound drivers on Windows can do that automatically, by jack-sensing.  You can accept your own answer, by the way.

Comment: @paradoid: I know that, but I can only accept my own answer tomorrow (I think this is done to avoid spam abuse).

Comment: Version not compatible with OSX 10.8.3